# Granger Causality in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to run the Granger causality test for a list of variables and have the following macro to do that in SAS -

```
%MACRO GRANGER();   
     %DO I = &START. %TO &END. ;  
        %LET VAR1 = &&VAR1_&I.;
        %PUT &INDEPVAR1. ;

        PROC VARMAX DATA= COMB ;
            MODEL Y1    &VAR1.  / DFTEST P=1;
            CAUSAL GROUP1 = (Y1) GROUP2 = ( &VAR1.);
            OUTPUT OUT = Results&I.;            
        RUN;


    %END; %MEND;
```

I want an output like this in a Sas dataset -

```
    Group1     Group2      Pr > Chisq
    Y1          Var1        <0.0001
    Y1          Var2         0.5690
    Y1          Var3         0.0134
    .........
```

But when I use the Out statement in Proc Varmax, it does not output the significance level. Instead it gives me a series of residuals, predicted Y1 etc. How do I just pull out these fields?

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/01/09/ods-output-any-statistic.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want the [OUTSTAT=](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63939/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_varmax_sect042.htm) option in the PROC VARMAX statement?